# How to fix pandas error 'Population must be a sequence. For dicts or sets, use sorted(d).'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I created a dataframe `df` which holds my browser history.
[An example of one of the rows is given here. Please look at it:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7gmZ.png)

The problem is I want to use the random.sample() function to filter the data to hold 50 domains (ex:Netflix) which are not secure. However, when I run the code I'm getting the error: `Population must be a sequence.  For dicts or sets, use sorted(d).`

The code:

```
import random

# Manual inspection, picking 50 random domains which were insecure
random.sample(df\[df\["is_secure"\] == False\].domain.unique(), 50)
```

Error:

```
Population must be a sequence.  For dicts or sets, use sorted(d).
```

Answer (score 0):

The error speaks for itself. `random.sample()` expects a sequence, like a list / tuple. Try converting it to a list before using a `random` library:

```
random_domains = random.sample(df[df['is_secure'] == False].domain.unique().tolist(), 50)
```

Update:
`error: 'Sample larger than population or is negative.'`

Most likely `df['url']` contains less than 50 unique values, which is why the error is raised. To avoid this in the future let's create a variable that will count the unique values:

```
num_sample = len(set(df['url']))
```

We then use this variable in our initial code snippet:

```
random_domains = random.sample(df[df['is_secure'] == False].domain.unique().tolist(), num_sample)
```

As @juanpethes suggested, we can also improve the inspection of the results by creating a mask to apply to the main dataframe. This will give us all rows from the dataframe corresponding to the selected domains:

```
df_random_domains = df[df['url'].isin(random_domains)]
print(df_random_domains)
```

Comment: What if we for easier inspection want the rows of the dataframe in which these 50 domains are selected from, rather than just a bare list, i.e. all the time, url, category etc?

Comment: After I append the tolist() function, I'm getting a new error 'Sample larger than population or is negative.'

Comment: @juanpethes for doing so we can create a mask as a next step. Smth like: ```df_random_domains = df[df['domain'].isin(random_domains)]```

Comment: @Srijan I've updated the initial answer

Comment: I am getting the same error 'Sample larger than population or is negative'. Your solution makes sense, can you think of how to fix this issue?

Comment: @Srijan it's hard to understand why an error raises without a data set in this case